# При вызове функции получаю undefined, при выполнении тела функции - true/false

Tags: javascript, функции

### Задача:

Получить список инпутов.

Если аттрибут `checked` - проверить его по `id` на предмет надобности.

Если нужный - вернуть `true`, ненужный - `false`.
Когда я беру "тело фукнции" и вставляю в консоль - проверка срабатывает корректно и я вижу в консоли `true/false`.
Если же я вставляю функцию полностью и вызываю её `neededTypeCheck()` - получаю `undefined`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема. Спасибо.

```
function neededTypeCheck() {
    let children = document.querySelector('#id').getElementsByTagName('input');
    let arrId = [];
    for (var [key, child] of Object.entries(children)) {
        arrId[key] = child.id;
    }
    arrid.some(function (id) {
            if (document.getElementById(id).checked) {
                if (id === 'reserved name' || id === 'reserved name 2') return false;
            } else return true;
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: поставьте `return` на седьмой строке перед `arrid.some(`

Comment: @DiD Благодарю, помогло. Если я правильно понял - в моём коде при return я выходил из анонимной функции в функцию neededTypeCheck(), которая уже ничего не возвращала?

Comment: Да, при этом консоль не требует слово `return` и всегда выводит результат последней команды.